# windows environment variable PATH from cache

Tags: windows, powershell

Whenever we change PATH variable value it will take effect until we do refresh or reboot the server and I suspect that the old PATH variable value is cached somewhere. Is there any way to get that cached PATH variable value to compare against the registry PATH variable value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes are not at all dynamic by nature. When you change environment variables for Windows, then other processes need to be restarted to reflect the new changes.

So you can't expect that all the processes that were using the old path will get the changes just by clearing the cache.

But a reboot will do your work. It is not cached in the windows level, its cached with each application level who ever is reading the value from the PATH variable.

Although, a temp cache is there to hold the value. but still that will be wiped out once you will do a reset.

Hope it gives you the logical set off.

Comment: got it! Is it possible to get the temp cache value?

Comment: never..if you open run-> %tmp% -> hit enter , there it will hold in any of those value , but also not necessarily